# Is there an option to specify multiple user names for remote execution on the same node?

Tags: rundeck

Is there anyway i can access the same node via 2 different users (appuser,webuser) to execute scripts? 
Will it be ambiguous if there is another entry made for the same node with different username?

```
    test1:
    hostname: "10.35.20.76"
    nodename: "test1"
    osArch: "x86"
    osFamily: "unix"
    osName: "Solaris"
    osVersion: "11.4"
    tags: "TEST"
    username: "appuser"
```

Answer (score 0):

A good option to do that is to use a job option pointing to your resources file, in this way:

Job Definition example:

```xml
<joblist>
  <job>
    <context>
      <options preserveOrder='true'>
        <option name='opt1' value='vagrant' />
      </options>
    </context>
    <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
    <description></description>
    <dispatch>
      <excludePrecedence>true</excludePrecedence>
      <keepgoing>false</keepgoing>
      <rankOrder>ascending</rankOrder>
      <successOnEmptyNodeFilter>false</successOnEmptyNodeFilter>
      <threadcount>1</threadcount>
    </dispatch>
    <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
    <id>eaf3f18e-97c0-4c85-b2fd-9a0b8dd8696e</id>
    <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
    <name>HelloWorld</name>
    <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
    <nodefilters>
      <filter>name: node00</filter>
    </nodefilters>
    <nodesSelectedByDefault>true</nodesSelectedByDefault>
    <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
    <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
      <command>
        <exec>echo "done"</exec>
      </command>
    </sequence>
    <uuid>eaf3f18e-97c0-4c85-b2fd-9a0b8dd8696e</uuid>
  </job>
</joblist>
```

Resources.xml example (check the "username" attribute):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project>
  <node name="mylocalhost" description="Rundeck server node" tags="" hostname="mylocalhost" osArch="amd64" osFamily="unix" osName="Linux" osVersion="5.15.0-66-generic" username="jdoe"/>
  <node name="node00" description="Node 00" tags="" hostname="192.168.33.20" osArch="amd64" osFamily="unix" osName="Linux" osVersion="4.10.0-1062.4.1.el7.x86_64" username="${option.opt1}" ssh-key-storage-path="keys/rundeck"/>
</project>
```

Also, you can do the same using passwords. Take a look at [this](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/projects/node-execution/ssh.html#ssh-password-with-a-job-option).